# two xmlhttp functions on onclick from dropdown

Tags: javascript, onclick, xmlhttprequest

After much research and failure, I am trying to refresh multiple div's from one onclick event on a dropdown. I can refresh single div's with the onclick event from the dropdown but cannot work out multiple. Several stackoverflow pages refer to similar issues with onclick but not a dropdown unless I missed it.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
function load_location(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("location_dd").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("location_dd").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ticket_new_user_location.php?property_id="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function load_drive_mapping(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("drive_mapping_cb").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("drive_mapping_cb").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ticket_new_user_drive_mapping.php?property_id="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

DROPDOWN

```
<select class="required" name="select_autos" onchange="load_location(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select Auto</option>
 <option value="1">Volvo</option>
 <option value="2">Ford</option>
 <option value="3">BMW</option>
 <option value="4">SAAB</option>
</select>
```

DIV's

```
<div id="drive_mapping_cb">
```

I can make each one work individually by switching the onclick from load_location(this.value) to load_drive_mapping(this.value) but cannot get both to work on a single onclick event.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just run both functions

```
onchange="load_location(this.value); load_drive_mapping(this.value);"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I eventually grouped all the dynamic fields into one div so I only had one onchange function.